# Api for adding users to a circle in google-plus?

Tags: java, google-plus

In the google plus API is it possible to search for users based on a username ?  If so where is this documented ?

Reading the section 'Fetch people information' in https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java this is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, there's a feature request open for it that you can star: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=47